# Authenticating end users in a first-party native app

Tags: node.js, security, authentication, google-cloud-platform

We are in the process of developing a mobile (native) app, and are looking at how we should do user authentication. Most of the information I have found have been about web apps and / or third-party apps accessing public APIs. OAuth 2 is therefore recommended to be used most of the time.

Since we develop the app and our API isn't public, it seems like the Resource Owner Password Credentials OAuth 2 flow could be an option, but according to [oauth.net](https://oauth.net/2/) that is not recommended any more.

We are using Google App Engine (with Node.js) and Cloud Endpoints (Not sure if end-points would be needed since it's a private API, but that is another question) as the back-end, and both Firebase Auth and Auth0 has built in support in Endpoints. However, we have some special requirements that doesn't make those services suitable (Swedish BankID for example).

What other options are there when authenticating users? Could we write an app in App Engine to check the users credentials against our database, and then send back a JWT (Cloud Endpoints supports custom authentication methods as long as they use JWT)? Would it be safe to do this ourselves? I have found some Node.js libraries for authentication, but most seem to be aimed at web apps. Are there any that are suited for a native app front end?

Comment: I am in a similar situation.  We use GAE Standard and Google Cloud Endpoints.  In our web app, we authenticate users with email/pwd.  We'd like to use this for mobile apps too.  We don't want to use OAuth, but instead use our email/pwd scheme for authenticating users.

Closest thing I can find that would be suitable is Using A Custom method to authenticate users: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authenticating-users-custom.  However, it is short on implementation details.

Comment: I agree that there should be more documentation. What we will probably end up doing is creating a POST method in App Engine that checks the username / password and then creates a JWT that is sent back and saved in the app. That JWT is then added in the header of every request that is sent to endpoints. After that I'm not 100 % sure what to do next since I haven't used endpoints before. But endpoint should check the token more or less automatically if everything is set up correctly

Answer (score 1):

For authentication, yes, you can perform the check yourselves, in your database and deliver or not a JWT according with the authentication result.

However, and it's obvious, this authentication service must be public (because it's for authenticated unauthenticated users!). And thus, you can be expose to attacks on this service. And because it's the authentication service, if the service goes down, no one can no longer sign in, or worse, if you have a security breach, your user database can be stolen.

That's why, to use existing services, with all the protections, all the resources (people, monitoring, automatic response, high availability,...) deployed to managed a large number of threats. Firebase auth, Auth0, Okta (...) are suitable providers but I don't know your Swedish requirement and you might not avoid specific developments

Comment: Thanks for your input! Swedish bankID is an electronic identification system. Maybe it is worth using something like Auth0 to not have to deal with possible security vulnerabilities

Comment: Yes it's my best answer. There are experts and dedicated teams for this.